# Android application get force close when try repetedly scroll up and down List view

Tags: android

I make a list view which have Text and Images IN side List using custom list adapter. It works well but when I scrolling the list view repeatedly up and then application get crashed and in log cat it shows problem in Heap size.

What should I do to solve this issue? The problem is not occurring on Low Api version when I tested the application on HTC one V(4.0 API), then only it get crashed on scrolling, it works scroll, 3 or 4 times but doing more scrolling it hung and get force close with heap size problem.

Stack trace:

```
I/dalvikvm(20978):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 07:58:33.796: E/dalvikvm(20978): Out of memory: Heap Size=131107KB, Allocated=130843KB, Limit=49152KB
09-03 07:58:33.796: E/dalvikvm(20978): Extra info: Footprint=131043KB, Allowed Footprint=131107KB, Trimmed=1096KB
09-03 07:58:33.796: D/skia(20978): --- decoder->decode returned false
09-03 07:58:33.796: D/AndroidRuntime(20978): Shutting down VM
09-03 07:58:33.796: W/dalvikvm(20978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab8228)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=131107KB, Allocated=130843KB)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFile(Native Method)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:373)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:443)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at com.raila.controller.ImageDownloader.download(ImageDownloader.java:90)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at com.raila.view.NewsActivity$ItemsAdapter.getView(NewsActivity.java:166)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2054)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2004)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:889)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:829)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4636)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3899)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:607)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-03 07:58:33.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20978):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 07:58:33.977: I/dalvikvm-heap(20978): Clamp target GC heap from 134.749MB to 128.000MB
09-03 07:58:33.987: D/dalvikvm(20978): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 1% free 130500K/131043K, paused 2ms+33ms
09-03 07:58:36.379: D/Process(20978): killProcess, pid=20978
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide us your stacktrace

Comment: Please Refer Question Part now..i have been added

Comment: 09-03 15:10:31.946: D/Process(1607): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.trimApplications(ActivityManagerService.java:15565)
09-03 15:10:31.946: D/Process(1607): com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:13406)
09-03 15:10:31.946: D/Process(1607): android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:336)

Answer (score 1):

you should watch the video "[the world of listview](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" for better understanding of how listview (and any other adapterView) works .

another good thing to check out is how to [handle bitmaps in an efficient way](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

also , you should cancel a viewholder task each time you reach the getView function , so that old tasks won't change the content of the "new" view to show.

Answer (score 0):

The error is when using Bitmaps. When you scroll, you are loading new bitmaps on and on so at some point you run out of memory.
You must call "recycle()" on Bitmaps when they are no longer displayed. There's a post on the Android Developer Blog that shows how to do this right.
Check out http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html and http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: VV thanks to You Phillipe for Replying...I used Lazy loading for Downloading image and display them so now where should i use View Holder class and How to Perform recycle for bitmap ..